# Rails + Ajax render multiple time during while loop

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a form that is send asynchronously thanks to `remote: true`

Inside my controller I have a loop because it needs to execute some particular action multiple times.

Today I render only the result when the loop is finished and it's working but I would like to be able to render a progression **each loop time**, but when I use `respond_to` inside the loop there is an error

> AbstractController::DoubleRenderError (Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action.)

I also already tried with `render_to_string` but nothing shows up.

How can I bypass that to render a progression percentage (for example) of the loop to the view?

---

My controller

```
def run
  while condition
    # perform some actions
    render_to_string :partial => "static_pages/message_sent", :locals => { :message_sent => "Some text<br />" }
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js{ render :partial => "static_pages/message_sent", :locals => { :message_sent => "Some text<br />" } }
    end
  end
end
```

My view

```
<%= form_tag("/run", method: "post", remote: true) do %>
  # Some form inputs
  <%= submit_tag("Start", :id => "start_script", data: { disable_with: "Wait..." }) %>
<% end %>

<br /><br />

<h3>Result :</h3>
<div id="script_output"></div>
```

Partial _message_sent.html.erb

```
$('#script_output').append("DOES IT SHOWS UP?"); # No it doesn't
```

run.js.erb (working only when the loop ends)

```
$('#script_output').append("<%= @output.html_safe %>")
```

Comment: there must be only one respond_to in a action or you will get the error

Comment: Move the block out of loop

Comment: @Deepak How can I get notified each time the while do a loop then ?

Comment: Your question seems legit but I think there must be some other ways than responding multiple times from action

Comment: You can't send multiple HTTP responses to one request. That's what you're trying to do right now. Look into websockets for realtime communication between two endpoints.

Comment: Alternatively you could have this route _start_ your long-running process and set up a separate route to _check_ the progress. Then set up a loop client-side to poll this every x seconds. Here's a [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/229-polling-for-changes?view=asciicast) about it.